# Java thread pool - is thread getting renewed?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Thread pool in my Java.NIO socket server.
I sometimes received runtime errors like `Connection reset by peer` or `Broken Pipe`, etc.

My question is: is the thread getting killed when an exception is thrown? If it is - is a new thread created in the thread pool in place of the killed thread??

This is my ThreadManager:

```
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class ThreadsManager {

    private ExecutorService threadPool = null;
    private LiveConnectionsManager liveConnectionsManager;
    private int threadPoolSize = 35; //number of tasks thread

    public ThreadsManager(LiveConnectionsManager liveConnectionsManager) {
        this.liveConnectionsManager = liveConnectionsManager;
        threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
        ServerActions.threadPool = threadPool;
    }

    public void processNewMessage(SocketChannel socketChannel, Client client)
    {
        threadPool.execute(new MessagesProcessor(socketChannel, client, liveConnectionsManager));
    }

    public void closeConnection(SocketChannel socketChannel, Client client) {
        threadPool.execute(new LogoutClient(socketChannel, client, null));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 12):

As you using **ExecutorService** to create thread pool.

So **yes**, **ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool(..)** ensures that number of threads are constant if they get killed by any exception/error and there are enough task waiting for thread. Below text from java doc states it clearly :

**Straight from java doc :newFixedThreadPool**

*Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of threads operating off a shared unbounded queue. **At any point, at most nThreads threads will be active** processing tasks. If additional tasks are submitted when all threads are active, they will wait in the queue until a thread is available. If any thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks. The threads in the pool will exist until it is explicitly shutdown.*

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)

Comment: and just to be sure - when a thread has an exception does it get killed ? or can it return to be idle ?

Comment: So as the specification says...if there is any failure during execution and thread gets killed then a new thread gets created.

Comment: It says "at most" because less threads can be available too. The threads get created only when they are needed and are not killed by the pool when unused. However the creation itself occurs only if a task waits in the queue and there is less than maximum threads available - so no, the number of threads is **NOT** constant.

Comment: agree..Executors create threads only when there is a demand for one until it reaches the set number. So i meant in idle condition when all threads are already created then executors makes sure that the pool has given thread. Have modified my comment to make it clearer. Thanks @theadam

Comment: That's still not correct. Even after the corePoolSize is saturated and some threads get killed during tasks execution, new threads still won't be created if there is nothing enqueued.

Your answer now suggests that after creating all corePoolSize threads the ThreadPoolExecutor will indeed immediately create a new thread if one of the active ones dies.

Comment: "So yes, ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool(..) ensures that number of threads are constant if"

Is there a way to simulate it cant create thread scenario ?

Answer (score 4):

The `ThreadPoolExecutor` does manage the number of threads based on the settings that you choose (passed in the constructor or via the helper method that you've used). It works just like described in ThreadPoolExecutor javadoc.

From the constructor (listed below) the most interesting parameters are `corePoolSize` and `maximumPoolSize`. `corePoolSize` is the lowest amount of threads that will remain alive. If a thread is killed and due to this the number of threads drop down below this number, new thread(s) will be started[1] (at some point).

`maximumPoolSize` is the max numbers of the threads in the pool. If this is higher than `corePoolSize`, your pool might end up with more threads then you've specified in `corePoolSize` parameter. If one of the threads die at this point and the number of live threads will not drop below `corePoolSize` number, then a new thread will NOT be created.

The fixed thread pool that you are creating via the **Executors** helper class has corePoolSize == maximumPoolSize, so indeed the service will make sure that the same amount of threads is always available[1] (when needed).

[1] **An important notice** is that the creation of the threads happens "on demand" - that is if a thread dies and there are no tasks in queue, then the thread will not be created until it will not be needed (by enqueuing above already available threads).

```
/**
 * Creates a new <tt>ThreadPoolExecutor</tt>( ... cut irelevant part ... )
 *
 * @param corePoolSize the number of threads to keep in the
 * pool, even if they are idle.
 * @param maximumPoolSize the maximum number of threads to allow in the
 * pool.
 * ( ... cut irelevant part ... )
 */
public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
                          int maximumPoolSize,
                          long keepAliveTime,
                          TimeUnit unit,
                          BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
    this(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue,
         Executors.defaultThreadFactory(), defaultHandler);
}
```

[EDIT] - forgot the other question.
Indeed, Exceptions do kill Worker threads - you need to handle errors internally.
For details check java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.Worker class. Its runTask method is worth checking.

Comment: :o u pasted the whole javadoc!!

Comment: Just from one constructor... Would cutting the irrelevant part really help?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: does the Thread getting killed when an error is catched ?
>
> and if it does - the thread pool fills it position in the pool with the new thread ?

The executor created by `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` will create a new thread if one of the threads in the pool dies, so the answer to the second part of your question is yes.  As for the first part, it's impossible to say without seeing the code of `MessagesProcessor` and `LogoutClient`, but given that any dead threads will be replaced, it doesn't really matter one way or the other.  If `MessagesProcessor` and `LogoutClient` catch and log the exceptions internally

```
public void run() {
  try {
    // do stuff
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

then the exception won't propagate out of the `run` method so won't kill the thread that is running the task, so it will be able to return to the pool.  But if they don't catch the exceptions, and they allow a `RuntimeException` to be thrown out of the `run` method then the thread will die (and be replaced by a fresh one).